# I want to use memcpy to copy from a certain byte in c

Tags: c, memcpy

I want to copy some part of data into source_mac

This is my code:

```
uint8_t *data
uint8_t *source_mac

memcpy(&source_mac, &data[6], 6);
```

So I want to copy 6 bytes from `data`, starting with the 6th byte in data, into `source_mac`... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your compiler complain about passing wrong type of argument for the destination? If you get and error or warning, show the exact and complete message in your question.

Comment: `&source_mac` this is the address of the pointer variable, not where it points to. Use `source_mac` or `&source_mac[0]`

Comment: Your pointer are uninitialized, so your `memcpy` call tries to copy 6 bytes from some random location (`&data[6]`) to wherever the `source_mac` variable is located (which depends scope, which is unclear from your incomplete code example). Even if `data` was properly initialized, passing `&source_mac` to `memcpy` overwrites the `source_mac` variable, not what it (should) point to.

Comment: You are asking for help for a function that is described on every CPP webpage. The first parameter is always the destination, never the source. And you are accessing to unallocated memory.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your code fragment:

- the 6th byte is `data[5]`
- you pass `&source_mac` as the destination, which is the address of the `source_mac` pointer, not the address of the destination array. You should either pass `&source_mac[0]` or simply `source_mac`

Here is a modified version:

```
void my_function(uint8_t *data, uint8_t *source_mac) {
    [...]
    memcpy(source_mac, &data[5], 6);
    [...]
```

Comment: I always get an segmentation fault, when i use the code you provided

Comment: @hannah: I did not provide a full program, can you post the source to the program that causes a segmentation fault? Add an **EDIT** paragraph at the end of your question and post the code surrounded by ``` quotation marks